# Get ParseUser by username

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

In unity (c#) how i get a Parse user with a specific username?

I tried several ways but i get always the same error:

You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.400 Bad RequestUnityEngine.WWW:get_text()Parse.<>c__DisplayClass36:b__2a(WWW)Parse.<>c__DisplayClass20:b__1f()Parse.d__3c:MoveNext()

First Test:

```
yield return ParseUser.Query.GetAsync(userID).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ParseUser userRetrieved = t.Result;
        if(userRetrieved != null)
            {
                //userFound
            }
});
```

Second Test:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query=ParseUser.Query
    .WhereEqualTo("username",userID);
    yield return query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t=>
        {
            IEnumerable<ParseUser> results = t.Result;
            foreach(ParseUser pu in results)
                {
                    //userFound
                }
});
```

Third Test:

```
yield return ParseUser.Query
    .WhereEqualTo("username",userID)
    .FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            //userFOund
});
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have used parse using the following code and it works fine where `ParseObjectsName` represents the name of the table.

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery(ParseObjectsName.PlayerProfile.ToString())
                 .WhereEqualTo(PlayerProfileDataVariableName.ID.ToString(),ID);
```

query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
   {

`IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
        List<ParseObject>  totalResultsForQuery = new List<ParseObject>();
        foreach(ParseObject obj in results)
        {
            totalResultsForQuery.Add(obj);
        }
   }`

In your case make sure you are setting the correct name for table name and variable name. 
Secondly, may be your internet was not working at that point of time. you should also check `t.isFaulted` or `t.isCancelled` before trying to check the result.